# Android app crashes in corner case: open the Question options again after tapping share

Tags: bug, android-app

Observed in Android app version 1.0.42 on a HTC One running Android 4.4.2.

Just now, I wanted to edit a question. I tapped on the menu button that opens the *Question options* menu. That's this one, no tricky stuff here:

[image: the one that says 'Edited: 18 hours ago', or whatever]

Then I tap *Share* instead of *Edit* by accident. The *Question options* menu closed, and the *Share To...* menu opened. However, on my phone at least, there's a small portion of a second in which the *Question options* menu has totally closed again as if it's been dismissed, but the *Share To...* menu has not yet opened.

Hurriedly, to correct my mistake, during that less-than-a-second window, I tapped the menu button again (the one circled above). I'm not sure whether I intended to dismiss the *Share To...* menu, or actually reopen the *Question options* menu, but that's what I did.

And then the Android app crashed totally, because apparently it doesn't like opening the *Question options* menu when it's waiting on the *Share To...* menu.

[image: a horrible horrible crash]

Yes, that's my home icons *overlaid* over the Android app.

The briefer reproduction-steps version:

1. Tap the menu button circled above.
2. Tap *Share*.
3. Immediately repeat step 1 before the *Share To...* menu opens.
4. Observe crash.

Comment: I spent an unhealthy amount of time trying to reproduce this. But I was finally able to reproduce it on a Nexus 5 running Stock 4.4.4.

Comment: This no longer occurs with the menu changes in the current version.